# How can I view my wallet private key using Blockchain

Tags: client, blockchain.info, private-key-export

I have a newly created account at Blockchain and have read through a lot of tutorials explaining how to display a private key from a wallet stored on Blockchain. None of them are accurate to the current Blockchain UI.

I just want to view my wallet's private key. It is not a watch only wallet, I have full access to transfer funds from this wallet.

I believe other wallet clients can do this easily and it seems according to the vast number of old tutorials available Blockchain.info used to be able to do this.

[Edit]
I have solved this question myself and I will be posting a detailed answer to it soon.

Comment: If you post your answer here, you may also want to post a link to that answer over here where someone is asking a very similar question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49482/blockchain-retreive-public-key-and-private-key-from-wallet